# AutoMapper and inheritance: Resolve subclass type by string property

Tags: c#, inheritance, automapper, dotnetopenauth

Basically I have entities:

```
public abstract class SocialNetworkAccount
    {
        public virtual string AccessToken { get; set; }
        public virtual string ProviderUserId { get; set; }
        public virtual string UserName { get; set; }
    }
```

and subclasses:

```
public class FacebookAccount : SocialNetworkAccount
    {
        public virtual string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual string Link { get; set; }
        public virtual GenderEnum Gender { get; set; }
    }
public class LinkedInAccount : SocialNetworkAccount
{
    public virtual string LastName { get; set; }
    public virtual string FirstName { get; set; }
}
```

and i need map [DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet.AuthenticationResult](https://github.com/matejskubic/dotnetopenid/blob/master/src/DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet/AuthenticationResult.cs) to my entity.

`AuthenticationResult` has string property `Provider`

```
AuthenticationResult result = OAuthWebSecurity.VerifyAuthentication("...");
SocialNetworkAccount account = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<SocialNetworkAccount>(result);
```

but i need instance to be `FacebookAccount` or `LinkedInAccount` dependent on `result.Provider`.
Any help

Comment: What exactly `Provider` string contains? Type name?

Comment: contains string like `facebook`

Answer (score 1):

You should handle Provider value manually. I would suggest you to create mappings from AuthenticationResult to each social network account type you need. Then just call appropriate mapping in extension method:

```
public static SocialNetworkAccount ToSocialNetworkAccount(
   this AuthenticationResult result)
{
    switch(result.Provider)
    {
        case "facebook": return Mapper.Map<FacebookAccount>(result);
        case "linkedin": return Mapper.Map<LinkedInAccount>(result);
        // ...
        default:
           throw new ArgumentException("Unknown provider: " + result.Provider);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
AuthenticationResult result = OAuthWebSecurity.VerifyAuthentication("...");
SocialNetworkAccount account = result.ToSocialNetworkAccount();
```